# Flutter paint custom message bubble?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, and I want to create a message bubble like this:
[image]

(I know, there are libraries, but they don't look the same, and not customizable enough).
How can I create a Container that looks like this?

Comment: could you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [clipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) widget to do it. The only hard part will be to know the path associated to that bubble